# How to Index the Output in function

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

What I've tried is

```
read -p "Enter City In Australia: " city

function getaa {
    curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/$city/ | 
    json_pp | grep -E '"' | cut -d \  -f7-30 | cut -d: -f1 |  tr -d '"' |
    sed '1d'

}

getaa

#read -p "Enter City In Zip :" sub
#curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/$city/ | json_pp | grep -E '"' | cut -d \  -f7-30 | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '",,,' | sed '1d' | sed -n ${sub}p
```

And also after I've entered a city I want to output their zipcodes

My current output is:

```
Perth 
Perthville 
Perth Gpo 
North Perth 
Perth East
```

My expected output is:

```
1.Perth 
2.Perthville 
3.Perth Gpo 
4.North Perth 
5.Perth East
```

Comment: Why not just keep a counter and output the current count on each city entered, then increment count by `1`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 
How sir?

Comment: @IanJayloGuinto, if you could post output of `curl` in your post we could try to make it easy for you as expected output is there, please post it.

Comment: In order to help with the zip code issue, you need to post the raw output of what `curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/$city/` returns. We have no way of knowing what API you are using.

Comment: As far as the simple count goes, just `declare -i count=0` above your `read` somewhere. Then as the first line in `getaa` add `printf "%d." $((count++))`. Each time `getaa` is called, it will output `1.` before the first city, then `2.` before the second, etc..

Comment: Another option to number your output is to pipe the output of your process to `... | nl -s "." -w 1` (number lines, using `'.'` as the separator with a width of `1`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin this is the raw output 

{"result":"OK","message":{"East Perth":"WA 6892 (PO Boxes 1-827 & 6002-6892)","North Perth":"WA 6906 (PO Boxes)","Perth":"WA 6848 (GPO Boxes 9000-10000)","Perth Airport":"WA 6105","Perth Bc":"WA 6849 (PO Boxes 8001-8506)","Perth East St Georges Tce":"WA 6832 (PO Boxes 3001-3540)","Perth Gpo":"WA 6000","Perth St Georges Tce":"WA 6831 (PO Boxes 5000-5500)","Perthville":"NSW 2795","South Perth":"WA 6951 (PO Boxes)","South Perth Angelo St":"WA 6151 (PO Boxes)","West P

Comment: @IanJayloGuinto, please post any output of curl command or so in your post with CODE TAGS, comments are not meant for that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin (nl -s "." -w 1)  this almost save my problem but it only counts up to 9.

Comment: Increase the `-w` to however many digits you need. (e.g. `-w 3` for `0-999`) You can look at all the options at [nl(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl)

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add line numbers to the beginning of each line, then pipe your output through this:

```
cat -n
```

If you want to format the line number, sed can do this easily

Answer (score 0):

If the output of `curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/$city/` is:

```
{
    "result": "OK",
    "message": {
        "East Perth": "WA 6892 (PO Boxes 1-827 & 6002-6892)",
        "North Perth": "WA 6906 (PO Boxes)",
        "Perth": "WA 6848 (GPO Boxes 9000-10000)",
        "Perth Airport": "WA 6105",
        "Perth Bc": "WA 6849 (PO Boxes 8001-8506)",
        "Perth East St Georges Tce": "WA 6832 (PO Boxes 3001-3540)",
        "Perth Gpo": "WA 6000",
        "Perth St Georges Tce": "WA 6831 (PO Boxes 5000-5500)",
        "Perthville": "NSW 2795",
        "South Perth": "WA 6951 (PO Boxes)",
        "South Perth Angelo St": "WA 6151 (PO Boxes)"
    }
 }
```

The one you posted in your comment for DavidC.Rankin (and the truncated json is converted to a valid one and pretty printed here just for better visibility).

In your bash function you used `json_pp` just to pretty print your `json` from the `curl` request. Therefore I omit it.
If your `json` is simple, then the followign awk one-liner can solve your problem:

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN { RS = "{|}|}}|," } NR > 3 { gsub(/"/, "", $0); print NR-3"."$1 }' message.json
```

or

```
read -p "Enter City In Australia: " city
curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/examples-services/postcode/$city/ | awk -F":" 'BEGIN { RS = "{|}|}}|," } NR > 3 { gsub(/"/, "", $0); print NR-3"."$1 }'
```

That outputs:

```
1.East Perth
2.North Perth
3.Perth
4.Perth Airport
5.Perth Bc
6.Perth East St Georges Tce
7.Perth Gpo
8.Perth St Georges Tce
9.Perthville
10.South Perth
11.South Perth Angelo St
```

In awk you can change the default (`newline character`) record separator (`RS`) to any regular expression. We do it at the beginning of execution, before any input is processed. Also we change the field separator to a colon (`:`), note the `-F":"` option. Based on the simple example input and the regex provided we need to extract the records after the `3rd line` (`NR > 3`). The `gsub` function removes the double quotes (`"`) from each record then we print out the line number and the `1st field` (`$1`) separated by a period (`.`) as it is posted in your expected output. The line number is the changed value of the number of records built-in variable `NR` with the amount we shift our processing.